# Javascript return an OR statement?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Im trying to filter an array where the parameters can be "true", "false" or "true || false". I'm having issues finding a way to return the "true || false" part. Is this possible?

here is the code for the array filter:

```
const filtered = data.filter(entry => 
                    entry.brokerage == brokerage
                    && entry.insurance == insurance
                )
```

here is where im trying to return the true/false/true || false:

```
const brokerage = showInsurance && showBrokerage? true || false : showBrokerage ? true : false
const insurance = showInsurance && showBrokerage? true || false : showInsurance ? true : false
```

the brokerage and insurance variables will always return true and not true or false if showInsurance and showBrokerage are true

im using vue to build this out but i understand this is mainly a javascript question. I know this is a bit of a weird question, but if anyone has any tips or can help I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: `true || false` will always evaluate to true. Returning `true || false` does not really make sense.

Comment: This looks like a fumbled attempt to cast a boolean to a boolean. `&&` already has you covered, you don't need a ternary.

Comment: Consider adding a [mcve], explaining the difference between the actual result and desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming those values are both either literal `true` or `false` *and* the corresponding properties of `entry` conform to the same then this is the simplest approach:

```
const filtered = data.filter(entry => 
            entry.brokerage == showBrokerage
            && entry.insurance == showInsurance
)
```

That casting code is not only confused and tangled up in itself, but isn't even necessary.

If you have a situation where `showBrokerage` might also be `undefined` in which case it doesn't go in the `filter`, then that's a different story. For that you'd want to do a multi-pass operation, conditionally applying `filter()` operations, like `if (condition) { set = set.filter(...) }`

Comment: How is `&&` with nothing preceding it even valid code?

Comment: @RobertRocha That was in the original, removed here.

Comment: @RobertRocha sorry, i deleted some other bits and forgot to take out the first &&

Answer (score 1):

Using `==` creates unnecessary complexity, which is one of the reasons you had to ask the question in the first place.
In other words, the advantage of using loose type operators is greatly outweighed by the disadvantage of its result not being straight forward (easy to predict without actually testing it) for most developers.

Apart from that,

```
const brokerage = showInsurance && showBrokerage? true || false : showBrokerage ? true : false
```

can be rewritten as

```
const brokerage = !(!showInsurance || !showBrokerage) || !!(showBrokerage);
```

or as

```
const brokerage = !(!(showInsurance && showBrokerage) && !showBrokerage);
```

---

As per your specific question around `true || false`:

The [Logical OR `||` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) returns the value of the first operand when this value is truthy and the value of the second operand in all other cases. Notably, the second operand is never evaluated if the first operand is truthy (thus returned).

In the case of `true || false`, because `true` is truthy, it gets returned and `false` is never evaluated. So, in effect, `true || false` is a more verbose way of writing `true`.

Because the second operand never gets evaluated, it can even be invalid JavaScript:

```
true || invalidExpression // returns true
```